# Can't use string as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use

Tags: perl

I am trying to execute the below mentioned code and observed the error

> Can't use string ("RCSoWLAN;ePDG-2;Qguest;ASUS_ATT_"...) as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use.

#### Perl code

```
#!/perl64/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $result_string = 'RCSoWLAN;ePDG-2;Qguest;ASUS_ATT_VOWIFI;RCS_IWLAN;Qguest;Pandora;Hydra;ASUS_ATT_VOWIFI_5G;Linksys_Performance_2.4G;RCS_NAT;ePDG7;Qguest;Pandora;Hydra;ipv6testap;Linksys_Performance_5G;ASUS_stress_5G;Hydra';

my $index = 1;

foreach ( @{ $result_string } ) {

    print "SSID[$index]: $_->{$index}->{ssid}\n";
    $index++;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As the error message says, `@{ $result_string }` tries to dereference the string as if it were an array reference. But it's just a string, so Perl can't do it for you

It looks as though you have semicolon-separated data, and the easiest approach is to use `split` to separate it into fields

This should work better for you

```
for ( split /;/, $result_string ) {

    print "SSID[$index]: $_\n";
    ++$index;
 }
```

but I can't follow what you're trying to do with `$_->{$index}->{ssid}`. Perhaps you would explain?

Comment: Hi, 
Thanks for your help!!
I am the beginner in PERL coding and facing below error this time after making the changes that you suggested: Can't use string ("RCSoWLAN") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use 

#!/perl64/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $result_string= 'RCSoWLAN;ePDG-2;Qguest;ASUS_ATT_VOWIFI';
my $index = 1;

for ( split /;/, $result_string ) {

            print "SSID[$index]: $_->{$index}->{ssid}\n";
   $index++;
         }

Answer (score 4):

$result_string is initialized with a string value. You cannot dereference a string value as an array reference.

If you want to split the string on semicolons, use [split](http://p3rl.org/split):

```
my @results = split /;/, $result_string;
```

You can then iterate over `@results`:

```
for my $result (@results) { ...
```

You haven't explained how the structure should be populated from the string, so I can't help you with the rest of the code.

Comment: Then it will fail at `$_->{$index}->{ssid}`

Comment: @ikegami: I have no idea how the structure should be populated from the string.

Comment: Neither do I. .